# T470p wifi is not working (intel 8265) on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, lenovo, intel, ubuntu-drivers

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a new laptop:

```
Lenovo ThinkPad T470p Intel Core i7-7700HQ 2,8GHz 8GB DDR4
256GB SSD M.2 35,6cm (14'') 1920x1080 Pixel Sound/LAN onboard VGA Nvidia GeForce 940MX WLAN Bluetooth
```

The wifi is not working and is not even recognized.

```
lshw -C net
*- network UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
product: Intel Corporation
physical id:0
bus info : pci@0000:03:00.0
version 78
width:64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: cap_list
resources: memory:ff220000-f2201fff
```

I have tried the official driver from the Intel site but there still has been no change.

Answer (score 2):

Your wireless device, the Intel 8265, is indeed supported in later kernel versions; specifically 4.6 and later. Ubuntu 16.04 uses the slightly older 4.4.0-xx kernel. You can verify from the terminal:

```
uname -r
```

I recommend that you install Ubuntu 17.04 which runs kernel version 4.10.0-xx and fully supports your device.